# Pop up a browser window upon selecting a choice

Tags: node.js, botframework

Using `Microsoft bot` framework I'm attempting to pop up a browser window, after a user selecting a certain option from `builder.Prompts.choice` only one of the options needs to directed to website.

How would do I this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a CardAction in a HeroCard of type 'OpenUrl', for example. From the ContosoFlowers sample in BotBuilder Samples:

```
          var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .text(messageText)
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, checkoutUrl, 'add_credit_card'),
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, session.gettext(RestartMessage), RestartMessage)
            ]);

          session.send(new builder.Message(session)
            .addAttachment(card));
```